# Can all bidirectional relations be LAZY?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using Spring with JPA (Hibernate).

As I was learning from many sites about relations (there are few ways of implementing each of them) there was also talk about fetching types, but question I asked here was never fully answered.

I'd like to know if there are cases where bidirectional relation CAN'T be lazy?
Can unidirectional also not be lazy sometimes?

By example:
Suppose there are many `Box`es in one `Warehouse`. Given this is ManyToOne relation (as said, few ways of implementing it, for sake of this example let's say `Warehouse` is owning side) - can it be lazy on both ends (you can load `Box`, and lazily `Warehouse`, but loading `Warehouse` will not load all `Box`es it has, only when you actually get them)?

How would such snippet look - do I just annotate both ends with JPA's LAZY, or some other, maybe Hibernate-specific thing?

Answer (score 5):

All relationships can be Lazy, and from Hibernate docs the recommendation is to mark all as lazy: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#fetching-strategies

> The Hibernate recommendation is to statically mark all associations lazy and to use dynamic fetching strategies for eagerness. This is unfortunately at odds with the JPA specification which defines that all one-to-one and many-to-one associations should be eagerly fetched by default. Hibernate, as a JPA provider, honors that default.

You would just mark both sides of the relationship as lazy:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "...", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
```

The defaults  for the mappings (if you don't specify `fetch`) are:

```
OneToMany: LAZY
ManyToOne: EAGER
ManyToMany: LAZY
OneToOne: EAGER
```